# Android: Detecting either XML or JSON data types of a BasicHttpResponse after PUT/POST

Tags: android, xml, json

I need to parse the server response from my http post & puts.   I originally thought all responses were going to be XML.   Now I'm finding out that, for certain calls, the response I'm getting back is JSON.   I have no control over the server, so changing this is not an option.

So,I need to decide the best way to detect the data type coming back from the server.  My first thought would be to attempt to parse the response as a JSON.  If a JSONException is thrown, assume it is XML.

Since I have no control over the server, I'm not sure I can count on the headers being correct.

Does anyone have any thoughts on the best approach?

Comment: If you are set on using the JSON parser included in Android you're going to have to call EntityUtils#toString(Entity) or something similar anyway, so just dropping whatever #toString(Entity) returns into a new JSONObject(String) and trying XML if parsing the response fails should be sufficient.

Comment: JSON always starts with '{' and XML with '<'?

Comment: and potentially some whitespace depending on how wonky the server producing the output is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I had stated in my question, I had no control over the server and could not count on it to be set up correctly and/or be passing the appropriate headers.  Otherwise, this would have been the obvious answer.

My original idea is what ended up working best:

"My first thought would be to attempt to parse the response as a JSON. If a JSONException is thrown, assume it is XML."

Answer (score 2):

Just look at the [content-type header](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentType%28%29) in the html response. If the server is working properly, that should tell you want type of content you're getting.

Comment: Down voter, care to comment? What am I missing here? Is there something wrong with my answer?